# Split HTML Canvas into rows with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, split, html5-canvas, effect

I'm trying to create an animated glitch effect using JavaScript and HTML Canvas. I have managed to draw my image onto a canvas and want to write a separate function that later splits this image into rows so they can be animated individually.

I call my function to create the canvas...

```
var logo_text = "logo_text.png";

drawOnCanvas(logo_text, mc_logo_text, 0, 0, 245, 60);
```

And here's what the function looks like...

```
function drawOnCanvas(image, divID, posX, posY, wid, hei) {

//////////// CREATE CANVAS /////////////

var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = wid;
    canvas.height = hei;
    canvas.id = divID.id+"_canvas";
    divID.appendChild(canvas);

//////////// DRAW IMAGE /////////////

var img = new Image();

    img.src = image;

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, posX, posY, wid, hei);
    } }
```

This function works fine and draws the image where I need it. I just can't figure out the best way to split this into rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this!**

You just need to edit the settings in each object of `_config` array.

> `drawOnCanvas()` will do same times equal the object's number in `_config`.

By the way, the scripts need to import below the `DIV`s , so `document.getElementById` could find them.

```
<body>
    <div id="mc_logo_text1"></div>
    <div id="mc_logo_text2"></div>
    <div id="mc_logo_text3"></div>

    <script>
        // Simply edit all settings here
        var _config = [
            {
                src: 'logo_text.png',
                domDiv: 'mc_logo_text1',
                position: {x: 0, y: 0},
                size: {w: 245, h: 60}
            },
            {
                src: 'logo_text.png',
                domDiv: 'mc_logo_text2',
                position: {x: 0, y: 0},
                size: {w: 245, h: 60}
            },
            {
                src: 'logo_text.png',
                domDiv: 'mc_logo_text3',
                position: {x: 0, y: 0},
                size: {w: 245, h: 60}
            }
        ]

        /////// No Need to modify ////////
        var drawOnCanvas = function(config) {

        var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            //Define which DIV to include new Canvas
            var domTaget = document.getElementById(config.domDiv);

        // Create Canvas & give new ID name
        function _canvasInit() {    
            canvas.width = config.size.w;
            canvas.height = config.size.h;

            canvas.id = domTaget.id + "_canvas";
            domTaget.appendChild(canvas);
        }

        // draw images into canvas
        function _drawImgs() {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = config.src;

            img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, config.position.x, config.position.y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        }

                // Do all functions
        _canvasInit();
        _drawImgs();
        }

        // Each object in _config array do drawOnCanvas function,
        for (var i = 0; i < _config.length; i = i + 1) {
            drawOnCanvas(_config[i]);
        }
        /////// No Need to modify ////////

    </script>
</body>
```